# Ошибка processing of -javaagent failed при запуске Coverage

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При запуске тестов с помощью плагина Coverage (в IDEA 2016.1.3) выдает ошибку `FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed`.

Без плагина все работает отлично. Пробовал снести всю Java и IDEA и переустановить — не помогло. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Полный текст ошибки:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.main.CoveragePremain.premain(CoveragePremain.java:66)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.intellij.rt.coverage.instrumentation.Instrumentator.premain(Instrumentator.java:64)
    ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Версия Java — Java SE Development Kit 8u91.

Comment: А версия java какая?

Comment: Java SE Development Kit 8u91